# Using SHA-256 (or SHA2 family) hashing algorithm with ASP.NET Identity 2.2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, algorithm, security, hash

I am working on a project that uses ASP.NET Identity 2.2.1. I have a requirement to use a SHA-2 family hashing algorithm for password hashing. The ASP.NET Identity 2.2.1 hashing algorithm is HMACSHA-1 (+ salt etc) and version 3 (In Beta) uses HMACSHA-256.

Source: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/PasswordHasher.cs

Can anyone help out with ideas to implement a SHA-256 hashing algorithm while using ASP.NET Identity version 2.2.1?